# ssh to a remote server and run a set of commands

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have 3 commands that i need to run on a remote server.

The 2 commands are simple version checks and 3rd command is basically a short program that checks version of my database. This is how it goes

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -t user@server << EOF

#AIP_version
domaininfo -d $GLOBAL_DOMAIN -history | head -n -3 | tail -1 > /home/abc/aip_version.txt

## Fetching AIP Online Details ##

variable1=$(
echo "set feed off
set pages 0
select * from system_parameters where name like '%VERS%';
exit
"  | sqlplus /@aipprealias01
)
echo "$variable1" > aipo_version.txt

#Fetching RPAS-AIP Details

domaininfo -d $GLOBAL_DOMAIN -version | sed -n '4,7p' > /home/abc/rpas-aip_version.txt

EOF
```

When I try to run this script, it gives me below errors :

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

-bash: line 8: SQL*Plus:: command not found

-bash: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `c'

-bash: line 10: `Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.'

I'd need help in understanding how can this error be resolved and secondly how can I run this script to do ssh on multiple servers rather than just 1 ?
Thanks!

Comment: You can try copying the file to the remote system manually and then run it there (just `ssh`). Does it work? make sure you are using the right shell. Once that works locally at the remote system, you can move on and try to `ssh -t` it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the heredoc marker from `EOF` to a single-quoted string, `'EOF'`. This will prevent the local shell evaluating `$( ... )` commands and `$variable` variables.

For example, contrast this with the single quotes around the `EOF` marker (as shown) and then without:

```
nl << 'EOF'
Numbered line
And another $(date)
EOF
```

Output with single quotes

```
 1  Numbered line
 2  And another $(date)
```

Output without quotes

```
 1  Numbered line
 2  And another 29 Dec 2021 16:20:40
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell substitute the *, run the command locally... Try this:

```bsh
    cat <your_script_body.txt>|ssh user@server "$(cat)"
```

your_script_body.txt :

```
#AIP_version
domaininfo -d $GLOBAL_DOMAIN -history | head -n -3 | tail -1 > /home/abc/aip_version.txt

## Fetching AIP Online Details ##

variable1=$(
echo "set feed off
set pages 0
select * from system_parameters where name like '%VERS%';
exit
"  | sqlplus /@aipprealias01
)
echo "$variable1" > aipo_version.txt

#Fetching RPAS-AIP Details

domaininfo -d $GLOBAL_DOMAIN -version | sed -n '4,7p' > /home/abc/rpas-aip_version.txt
```